# Unity error CS0103: The name `' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, mono

I have a generic class like this:

```
public class Connection<T> where T: Stream 
{
    protected T _stream;
    protected TcpClient _client;

    public void Connect(){/*Do somthing*/}
    public void Disconnect(){/*Do somthing*/}

    public void Reconnect()
    {
        Disconnect();
        Connect();
    }
}
```

I use VisualStudio as editor, it has no error but in unity editor console it says:

> error CS0103: The name 'Disconnect' does not exist in the current context

and

> error CS0103: The name 'Connect' does not exist in the current context

The line of the error is in the `Reconnect()` function.

**If I remove generic from this class, it hasn't any error.**
Is this a bug or I missed somthing?

Comment: make sure you have Visual Studio Unity Tools setup correctly. Make sure you don't have any hidden characters in the function definition. Or just switch to MonoDevelop for a second, maybe it will fix it for you.

Comment: there is no error in MonoDevelop too

Comment: I copy-pasted your code in my project, it's working fine. Are you using unity beta?

Comment: I'm using Unity 5.5.0p2. I've put the script in a separate file and imported System.IO; it's NOT in plugins folder.

Comment: How do you use your `Connection` class ? (meaning, how do you call the functions inside the Connecion class ?)

Comment: i want to use this class for creating `Connection<SslStream>` and `Connection<NetworkStream>`. their functionality is same like `Send` and `Receive`. I add some new information to question code.

Comment: @NikaKasradze,I'm using 5.4.1p2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it like this:

```
public abstract class BaseConnection<T>
{
    protected T _stream;
    protected TcpClient _client;

    public abstract void Connect();
    public abstract void Disconnect();
}

public class Connection<T> : BaseConnection<T> 
    where T: Stream 
{
    public override void Connect(){/*Do somthing*/}
    public override void Disconnect(){/*Do somthing*/}

    public void Reconnect()
    {
        Disconnect();
        Connect();
    }
}
```